# Mysql transactions, using LAST_INSERT_ID() in both the 2nd and 3rd query?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I am using this query to insert data into two different tables:

```
    $query1="INSERT INTO node (cid, title) VALUES('$cid','$title')";
    $query2="INSERT INTO location (nid, street, city, state) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$address', '$city','$state')";
    $result = FALSE;
    if (mysql_query('BEGIN')) {
        if (mysql_query($query1) &&
        mysql_query($query2))
        $result = mysql_query('COMMIT'); // both queries looked OK, save
        else
        mysql_query('ROLLBACK'); // problems with queries, no changes
    }
```

basically, the first query throws the data into the node table which in turn increments a NID field.  This NID is used in the second query (my location table).

Now I have changed my website a bit and I also want to insert that same NID into a 3rd table.  The problem is the second query (location table) also has an ID column (LID) that auto_increments as well, so if I try to use last_insert_ID it will just give me the LID and not the NID.

I was thinking I could do a 3rd query outside of the transaction where I would query the database and grab the correct nid, but I want to keep it inside of a transaction to prevent any mixups.  Any ideas?

Comment: Store the result of [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) in a PHP variable and then use that in your subsequent `INSERT` statements.

Comment: can I store it from within a transaction?  neither of the queries actually run until they are committed, so where would I store it at?

Comment: Actually, queries *run* when executed - they just aren't *committed* (to exist outside of the transaction) until you explicitly commit.  In particular, ids are incremented even if the transaction is rolled back - see [`AUTO_INCREMENT` Handling in `InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html): "*You may see gaps in the sequence of values assigned to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column if you roll back transactions that have generated numbers using the counter.*"

Comment: So would I have to add it inbetween     if (mysql_query($query1) &&
   mysql_query($query2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is only guaranteed to work once.

Best practice is to capture this value in your code directly after the query you want it after, either with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` or by using `mysqli_insert_id()`. Then you can insert it into later queries with impunity.

Comment: So would I have to add it inbetween if (mysql_query($query1) && mysql_query($query2)?  I cant seem to get it to work

Comment: Yes. I think you might need a somewhat less idealistic structure with your nested ifs.

Comment: how might I do that while still inside a transaction?

Comment: The transaction is independant of the code-branching. I would do this: Start the transaction. Do first query and set `$result` based on that. If the `$result` is true: retrieve the insert ID, then do the second query, and again set `$result` based on that. If `$result` is true: do the third query and yet again set `$result` based on that. If `$result` is true: commit the transaction, otherwise do a roll back.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks for your help